# Pass value into SharePoint timer job

Tags: c#, sharepoint, timer

I have a SharePoint timer job and in the `Execute` method I need to detect if the current execution was scheduled or if the timer job was run manually via Central Admin.

Is there a way to pass in a boolean or something to state whether this is scheduled or manually run?

My method constructor for the `Execute` is:

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
```